# Objective-CのPHFetchResultで拡張子を指定したい

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

現在、PHFetchResultを使用して、画像ファイルのみ取得しています。
以下のようなソースです。

やりたいことは、tiff画像を除外したいのですが、例えば、拡張子を指定して画像を取得、又は、拡張子を指定して画像を除外、みたいな書き方はできるのでしょうか？

```
// 作成日でソート
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];

// 写真のみ
PHFetchResult *assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
NSArray *assetArray = [self getAssets:assets];
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHAssetのリソースのuniformTypeIdentifierに画像フォーマットの情報が入っています。
以下のようにuniformTypeIdentifierを読んで、その値がpublic.tiff(kUTTypeTIFF)かをチェックすることでTIFF画像を除外できると思います。（このソースコードでは除外するところまでは行っていません。）

```
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType: PHAssetMediaTypeImage options: nil];
[result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset * _Nonnull asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    for (PHAssetResource *resource in [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:asset]) {
        NSLog(resource.uniformTypeIdentifier);  // この情報で判定する
    }
//    NSLog([asset valueForKey:@"uniformTypeIdentifier"]); // 別法
}];
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
早速実装し、tiff画像は除外できました。

ただカメラロールに画像が大量にあると、処理に大幅に時間が掛かり、現実的ではないので、別の方法（サーバ側でtiffをpngに変換）で対処することにしました。

ありがとうございます。